# the input won't equal to the string

Tags: java, methods, operators

As you might be able to see, i am a complete newbie to java. but i'm trying to make a rock-paper-scissor game.
But when i pass the input to the method, it doesn't return true, while the input is "rock". i checked.

What should happen, is that as the input is rock, true gets returned. now it just returns false.

thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game{

    static Boolean validInput(String input){
        if("rock" == input){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice;
        choice = input.nextLine();

        if(validInput(choice)){
            System.out.println(choice + " is valid input");
        }else{
            System.out.println(choice + " is not valid...");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, if you want to compare strings you must use .equals() instead of == 
So you would have

```
input.equals("rock")
```

This article will give you more in depth explanation :)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

This post might be helpful also
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)